# `for`-loop on python `sortedlist` does not iterate over all elements

Tags: python, sortedlist

I'm trying to go through a list, which is growing during the loop. For larger lists, I encounter a strange behavior, the iteration stops before going through all elements:

```
from blist import sortedlist

# for-loop
l = sortedlist(range(400))
for x in l:
    print(x)
    if x % 10 == 0:
        l.add(max(l) + 1)

print('last element:', l[-1])

# while-loop
l = sortedlist(range(400))
k = 0
while True:
    try:
        print(l[k])
        if l[k] % 10 == 0:
            l.add(max(l) + 1)
        k = k + 1
    except IndexError:
        break

print('last element:', l[-1])
```

Results:

```
.
.
.
430
431
last element: 443

.
.
.
443
444
last element: 444
```

This does not occur for a normal list. And the "while-loop" goes through all elements as I want. I suppose `sortedlist` are stored as trees structures, and somehow it does not play well with modifiying a list during a loop, but if anyone has more insight on this (and/or a clearer/better way to get the same behavior than the "while-loop")

Note that it is not a critical portion performant-wise, so I don't mind the log(n) access cost in the "while-loop" case.

Comment: I suggest you use a regular list for the loop, then sort it or generate a sortedlist from it.  It does not appear to have to be a sortedlist for the loop itself.

Comment: In my problem, I need to keep the list sorted. The new elements inserted during the loop are always greater than the current element but they don't appear in a sorted way, so I can't just `append` them (or I will have to sort the list at each insertion).

Comment: If the reason for keeping them sorted is just for the print statement, then why not print the sorted version in a separate loop?

Comment: The reason is more complicated : I'm selecting objects based on a score (higher is better), the score of an object can decrease based on previously selected object. At each step of the loop, I see if the score of the current object must be decreased (based on previously selected objects) and if yes I replace it at its new position in the list.

Comment: OK, so you are stuck with the `while ` loop then.

Comment: Quoting [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html) If you need to modify the sequence you are iterating over while inside the loop (for example to duplicate selected items), it is recommended that you first make a copy. Iterating over a sequence does not implicitly make a copy. Otherwise, the behavior is undefined.

Comment: I know, but my objective is not to edit the list. As explained in the previous comments, I'm selecting objects during the iteration, so I want the objects to be iterated in correct order (even those who are 'modified' during the loop). But it might be possible to do a double for loop, as cdarke suggested.

Answer (score 2):

### ORGINAL ANSWER

The reason is very simple. When you create a foreach loop over a collection, the loop retains a local copy of the information of the list it iterates through. This means it only iterates the length of your original lists (with no regards to any modifications).

The while loop just checks whether a condition is true for each iteration and does not keep a local copy of your list information.

### Modified answer

Based on your comment I tried to reproduce it but was unsuccessful. However this seem to produce what you want:

```
l = sorted(range(400))
for x in l:
    print x
    if x%10 == 0:
        l.append(max(l)+1)
        
print str(l[-1])
```

Comment: Except that the original list contains 400 elements, not 431. If the for loop made a local copy, it would have been 400 long.

Comment: I need to keep the list sorted during the loop. Elements appended during the loop don't appear in order (it's more something like `l.add(randint(x+1,1000))` )

Comment: I don't think i understand what it is exactly that you want to achieve. Can you update your question with a proper example and expected output? That would make it clearer.

Comment: My main goal was knowing why this occurs. This does not appear to be a local copy (or the loop would go through as many elements as there was in the original list, in this case : 400). So I was curious about the exact reason. I already achieved the behavior I desire using the "while-loop" (although it might not be very pythonic).